# Why define a function in a source file, then declare it in another before using its reference?

Tags: c

I found the following pattern in the DOOM source and I'm not sure what to make of it.

[The definition .c file](https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM/blob/master/linuxdoom-1.10/p_enemy.c)

[The declaration and use .c file](https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM/blob/master/linuxdoom-1.10/info.c)

`enemy.c`

```
// A nice definition, but there is no corresponding header file, kind of weird
void A_Pain (mobj_t* actor)
{
    if (actor->info->painsound)
    S_StartSound (actor, actor->info->painsound);   
}
```

`info.c`

```
// Now it's redeclared, but without a parameter?
void A_Pain();
// ...
state_t states[NUMSTATES] = {
// ...
    {SPR_PLAY,6,4,{A_Pain},S_PLAY,0,0}, // S_PLAY_PAIN2
// ...
}
```

Why wouldn't a header file be used, when the rest of the code base uses them?  Is there an advantage to this method?

Why declare the functions in a different source file with different signatures?

Comment: There were days, when you couldn't specify parameters in function declaration.

Comment: The *most likely* explanation is that this is a mistake that wasn't caught in review.  As long as the code calling `A_Pain` passes the right argument type, there won't be any runtime issues.  Depending on the compiler and the warning levels, no diagnostic may have been issued, or it may have been "just" a warning which was ignored.

Comment: @KamilCuk: Doom *is* old, but not *that* old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not good practice I think. But based on my understanding of the C standard, when you declare a function like `void A_Pain();` basically that function can take any number of parameters, which is different from C++. So in C you need to use `void A_Pain(void);` to say it has no parameter.

But in C++, `void A_Pain();` means that it takes no parameters.

Comment: The rest of the program is written with headers, except this part.  Is there any conceivable advantage to this approach?

Comment: One advantage I could think of is that if the signature of A_Pain changed, you just need to change enemy.C but you don' t need to change info.C. That being said that you still need to recompile both.

Comment: @MarvinIrwin you *would* expect consistency inside a codebase, but you would be wrong most of the time :)

Answer (score 0):

In C, the declaration `T f()` does not declare a function `f` returning `T` and taking zero parameters; it declares a function `f` returning `T` and accepting an unspecified number of parameters.

You can put function declarations in a source file even if the function definition is in a translation unit that your source file is not aware of, since joining it all together is done by the linker, not the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

> Why wouldn't a header file be used?

It doesn't make a real difference, header files are just textual inclusion anyway. It *makes sense* to put declarations in header files, especially if they're used in several places, but it's not *required*. As long as every compilation unit agrees on what the name means, things will work fine.

> Why declare the functions in a different source file with different signatures?

They don't have *different* signatures; if they did, there would be a problem. But the declaration in `info.c` has *no* parameter list. This is allowed as long as "the parameter list *[in the definition]* shall not have an ellipsis terminator and the type of each parameter shall be compatible with the type that results from the default argument promotions" (N1256 6.7.5.3, which is probably the wrong version of the spec for application to Doom, but it doesn't really matter). In other words, if a function is declared without a signature, the number and types of its parameters will be inferred from how it's called. As long as this inference is *correct*, you have a valid program that will work correctly. It's just old-fashioned, and because of the lack of explicitness, a bit harder to maintain.